# QueueTrigger to Write to Queue-Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, queuetrigger

I have a queuetrigger which reads a gis feature layer and process its as it writes back to portal. It seems to work alright except the message is not logged onto the outqueue. I say it works alright because I can see the gis featurelayer properly written on the gis portal. I suspect my bindings aren't alright. I don't need to necessarily have the resulting dataframe written back. All I need is any message deposited on the outqueue to resource other processes. Cant post whole code here for privacy but My main file **(init_py)** can be thought of as:

```
import logging
import json
import pandas


def main(msg: func.QueueMessage, msg1: func.Out[str]) -> None:
    logging.info('Python queue trigger function processed a queue item: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
       x=1
       y=1
       df=x=1
    
     msg1.set(df)
```

My **function.host**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "outqueue12",
      "connection": "storageaccountautom92bb_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
    "type": "queue",
    "direction": "out",
    "name": "msg1",
    "queueName": "outqueue13",
    "connection": "AzureStorageQueuesConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

binding accept string type and bytes type, so below code should work:

**`__init__.py`**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(msg: func.QueueMessage, msg2: func.Out[str]) -> None:
    num1 = 1
    num2 = 1
    str1 = num1+num2
    msg2.set(str(str1))
```

**`function.json`**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "test1",
      "connection": "0730bowmanwindow_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "msg2",
      "queueName": "test2",
      "connection": "0730bowmanwindow_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please add the function.json as well.

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573962/azure-webhooks-python` any help?

Comment: @wwnde I am watching the new question.:)

Comment: Think you could help?

Comment: @wwnde I just not sure. You want the webhook sender running continuously(when data in table changed, send request to httptrigger), right?

Comment: Yes, I think it has to be done through flask. I have tried following this documentation https://github.com/Azure-Samples/python-docs-hello-world but running int errors

Comment: @wwnde Ok, let me take a look of this doc.

Comment: This is also helping but not yet there https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNVvFttc-sA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227177/discussion-between-bowman-zhu-and-wwnde).

Comment: @wwnde Can we go to the chat room?:)

Comment: I have to go now for an urgent matter. Are you happy for us to chat tomorrow?

Comment: @wwnde OK. no problem.:)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?utm_source=pycon20&utm_medium=web&tabs=cmd&pivots=python-framework-flask

Comment: @wwnde  I'm already looking at your question

Comment: Cool, trying as well

Comment: I want to go for certain Azure Certification, have you done this before and are there things from your experience I should keep in mind? Please do me a favor and let me know. Happy to be guided on chat. Appreciate your help in advance

Comment: @wwnde I did something related to this. Maybe you can post a question. Or you can go to this place: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227671/certificate

Comment: I am attempting to read a GIS url with binary object. I need to deposit this in a blob storage using functions. Can you help? Happy to post question