# Azure Webhooks -Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, webhooks, azure-webhooks

I have an onsite SQL server which runs and  posts relevant records to to a data warehouse accessible via API endpoint. I need to create a webhook to detect changes whenever rows are added or deleted from the warehouse table.Preferably, the webhook should trigger a message to Azure queue storage via a httptrigger.

1. How can I go about this in azure? I cant get my hands on any straightforward documentation or tutorial.
2. If it cant be done in Azure, are there any other third party platforms with which I can create a webhook to detect changes to the table given the end points url?

I have been able to create a webhook in ArcGIS which is currently successfully running on the same logic. I am however now required to change and have that triggered by activity on the datawarehouse API. Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: Do you mean you want the function be trigger when the datawarehouse api be called ?

Comment: @Hury Shen, I have a URI which is a link with query parameters. How do I ensure when new data meeting a predefined search criteria is input, a http trigger is activated and message sent to queue. The difficulty I have here is creating a webhook or whatever you may want to call it to be listened to by the http trigger.

Comment: I don't think it can be implemented easily. May I know how did you call the warehouse api ? (what logic does the api run on ?)

Comment: In a normal code, I call and retrieve data from the api thus;`url = "https://url/operations?q=Active%20%3D1%20and%20LATITUDE%20%3D%20%20%220.000000%22%20and%20LONGITUDE%20%3D%20%220.000000%22&pageSize =300"

payload = {}
headers = {'Authorization': access_token.split('"')[3]}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
#print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
j=json.loads(response.text.encode('utf8'))`

Comment: Does that answer your query?

Comment: So why not request(trigger) the httptrigger function url directly after the code `response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)` ? Or I misunderstand your requirement ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226854/discussion-between-wwnde-and-hury-shen).

Comment: Question is pretty unclear, even after reading the comments. What code do you have control over, what code have you written? You want to trigger multiple Azure Functions when something is inserted into "an onsite SQL DW"? Azure Functions support a multitude of "triggers" and "bindings". "an onsite SQL DW" isn't one of them.

Comment: @Kashyap  thanks for looking into this. I have a data warehouse  endpoint. The data warehouse gets updated frequently. I need to create a webhook to detect any change. Preferably, an insertion in the data warehouse should trigger a message to be send onto queue storage. Please note the data warehouse is external to azure. Does that make sense?

Comment: You didn't quite answer the basic question: What code do you have control over, what code have you written? The code that inserts into this external data warehouse, OR your webhook implementation code that gets invoked by something when some data is inserted in the DW? I understand DW is external.

Comment: @Kashyap I have control over my webhook implementation code that gets invoked by something when some data is inserted in the DW. This code specific code is a http trigger. Did you want me to amend my question and include the code?

Comment: Can you update the question with what you're trying to achieve? Statements like `create a webhook to detect changes` make no technical sense.

Comment: `I have control over my webhook implementation`: Then just use [storage Q API](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-queue/12.1.4/index.html#sending-messages) to send the message to storage Q from that implementation?

Comment: @Kashyap, sorry it took me long to get back to you on this. See an updated query in this post. I ddi not want to delete this question because of the detailed discussions on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677939/how-can-i-create-a-python-webhook-sender-app